# Usecase for Constantly running tasks

Tags: jenkins

I have a few processes on my machine that I would like to have constantly running. I like however, how Jenkins organizes the jobs logging and I can go and see a build executing and see its STDOUT in realtime.

Would it be an issue to have a job that never finishes? I've heard after time there would be interruptions. Is there a better tool for something like this? Would basically love to be able to see the output from a web based perspective of the tool (and add hooks on failures)

For example if I were hosting a Node.js site, and wanted to be able to see the output of people connecting to the website or whatever is logged by the site. Ideally as long as you want to run the server, the process would be running constantly

Comment: IMO you should have your processes logging to a file or syslog and then use log monitoring tools to view them in realtime. While your use cases would be possible in Jenkins, it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @simon thats what I'm thinking, Its just nice to have the ability to start it when needing it